# Dask equivalent to Pandas replace?

Tags: pandas, dask

Something I use regularly in pandas is the .replace operation.  I am struggling to see how one readily performs this same operation on a dask dataframe?

```
df.replace('PASS', '0', inplace=True)
df.replace('FAIL', '1', inplace=True)
```

Comment: That should be quite simple to implement in dask if you raise an issue on the tracker: https://github.com/dask/dask

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use [`mask`](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.DataFrame.mask):

```
df = df.mask(df == 'PASS', '0')
df = df.mask(df == 'FAIL', '1')
```

Or equivalently chaining the `mask` calls:

```
df = df.mask(df == 'PASS', '0').mask(df == 'FAIL', '1')
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you! I kept playing around with `assign` and `where` but to no avail.  I obviously didn't quite make the connection to the functionality `mask` provides.

Answer (score 3):

If anyone would like to know how to replace certain values in a **specific column**, here's how to do this:

```
def replace(x: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
    return x.replace(
      {'a_feature': ['PASS', 'FAIL']},
      {'a_feature': ['0', '1']}
    )
df = df.map_partitions(replace)
```

Since we operate on a pandas' DataFrame here, please refer to [the documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) for further information

Comment: In the [map_partition](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.DataFrame.map_partitions)  you may want to add the `meta` argument