# Regex for mask function in Dask

Tags: python, pandas, dask

I have been using the following in pandas to replace some character with another using regular expression:

```
df = df.replace(r'\t|\r|\n', '', regex=True)
```

But as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40899044/dask-equivalent-to-pandas-replace), we have [mask](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.DataFrame.mask) in dask. But I do not find **how I can use regex** in this function. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried using `map_partitions`?

Comment: @mdurant How does that support regex matching?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most common way to deal with row-wise operations such as this is to use [`map_partitions`](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.Series.map_partitions), which allows you to work on each chunk of the dask-dataframe, each chunk being a real pandas dataframe.

In this example

```
df2 = df.map_partitions(lambda d: d.replace(r'\t|\r|\n', '', regex=True))
```

where `df` is a dask dataframe. Note that the function used with `map_partitions` expects a pandas dataframe and returns a pandas dataframe.

Comment: Looks promising. I will try and let you know. Thanks

Comment: I tried your solution and it worked. Just wondering though, what do you mean when you say that map_partitions expects pandas dataframe? In your example, you used a dask dataframe.

Comment: The input to the lambda function (`d`) is a pandas dataframe, parts of the larger dask dataframe.