# Dask equivalent of pandas replace

Tags: python, dataframe, dask

I would like to know if there is `dask` equivalent of pandas replace method. For example, I would like to change a **list** of values with one value. In the pandas case I could;

```py
df = df.replace(lst,val) #lst is a list where all of the values in the list if found in the dataframe should be changed to a value called val.
```

Would anyone be able to help me on this matter.

Thanks

Michael

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40899044/dask-equivalent-to-pandas-replace.

Comment: The duplicate does not work on lists. Thanks

Comment: In case you don't get an answer, the duplicate should work with a for loop.

Comment: ok thanks will check that.